# Python flask RESTful: Directory structure

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am fairly new to python and flask, I have created an authentication stystem, A JWT token based authentication. Currently my directory structure is :

> Note : If possible, Please answer in detail.

```
-Project
  -- venv (folder)
  -- models.py
  -- resources.py
  -- run.py
  -- views.py
```

As the names are self explanatory, models.py have a class which named `UserModel`, In resources,py there are many classes like `UserRegistration`, `UserLogin`, `UserLogoutAccess`, `UserLogoutRefresh`, `TokenRefresh`, `AllUsers`.

`run.py` have the server related and app initialization code, And also the endpoints resource are defined here like :

`api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')`

I know its messy, But also i have no idea about the python Flask conventions, Should each class have its own file, Should the authentication code be placed in one directory, As the project will obviously grow.

I am thinking about the following directory structure :

```
-Project
  -- venv
  -- Authentication
      -- login.py
      -- registration.py
      -- logout.py
      -- userLogoutRefresh.py
      ....
      ....
  -- Models
      -- UserModel.py
      ....
      ....
  -- run.py
```

> Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Look up Flasky.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I generally structure my Flask projects:

```
-- Project
  -- app
    -- models
      -- user.py
      -- inventory.py
    -- views
    -- routes
    -- static
      -- css
      -- images
      -- js
    -- templates
    -- utils
    -- ..
    -- settings
      -- local.py
      -- staging.py
      -- prod.py
  -- migrations 
  -- docs
  -- tests
  -- manage.py
```

This allows me more flexible and structured code when the project grows. For example, having single models.py could become difficult to manage for the larger projects and same goes with other as well.

Also, I prefer keeping virtual environment outside the project as that does not need to be pushed to the repository.

In a pure Rest API project, you might not require some parts of it like, templates, static etc.

Comment: So which folder contains my `resource.py` classes ?

Comment: I keep them under views. Also, routes directory should contain different route files, grouped based on different project modules. So all the routes related to users can go like `-- routes - > users.py`